# Speed of Sales defined as sales/running_days

Tags: python, datetime, group-by

I have a transaction sales dataframe:

```
print(df)

dt_op      quantity      cod_id
20/01/18      1            100
20/01/18      8            102

21/01/18      1            100 
21/01/18     10            102
...
```

And I would like to define a new variable "**speed**" as "cumulative_sales / **days_elapsed**_since_the_launch_of_**that**_product, for every different item in "cod_id".

I tried with:

```
start = min(df["dt_op"])

df["running_days"] = (df["dt_op"] - start).astype('timedelta64[D]')
df["csum"] = df.quantity.cumsum()

df["speed"] = df["csum"] / df["running_days"]
```

But it does not compute it **for every single item**; I would avoid for-loops for computational issues and slow running time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the first launching date for every 'cod_id' in a new column with grouby:

`df2 = df.groupby(['cod_id']).dt_op.min()`

and merge it back to your dataframe

`df = pd.merge(df, df2, on='cod_id', how='left')`

then create a new column as the data difference between the minimum date and the first one. And you can calculate the csum always like above and diveded through the date difference.